# What is uncovered by synchronizing at viewpoints?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

When you synchronize at a viewpoint in *Assassin's Creed Unity*, what locations are added to the map, and what things are only uncovered when you get close enough to them?

It's unclear to me, for example, if the Nomad and the locked chests are uncovered by this  mechanism.

Comment: Not confident enough to post as an answer without checking... but isn't it just like all other AC games? You should notice side quests/events/memories become visible, no? (As well as chests and the like)

Comment: @DangerZone not according to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/245903/are-the-microtransactions-necessary-on-assassins-creed-unity "Synchronizing viewpoints no longer marks all collectibles and missions on the map". It seems to mark some things, though, like unlocked chests?

Comment: If nobody answers by tonight and I'm not too lazy to start a new game, maybe I'll experiment a little and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I have unfortunately already used all of them also also ran around with eagle vision quite a lot before I wondered about this :-)

Answer (score 1):

When synchronizing a viewpoint, what is revealed is:

- Map
- Some Chests
- Available sidemissions

What is revealed on the map once seen with eagle vision

- Some Chests
- Artifacts
- Cockades
- Murder missions

The only thing that shows regardless of having activated a viewpoint or not are mission related icons (Kill/rob/search zones/Main mission icon)

Comment: I played a bit more after asking this question, and chests aren't uncovered by synchronizing. The rest sounds plausible, though.

Comment: Please note that some chests are revealed on viewpoint sync and the rest must be found with eagle vision